# Deducing elliptic regularity using spherical formula for Laplacian

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, laplacian

It is well known that if $\Delta u = f$ and $u\in H_0^1(U),f \in L^2(U)$ for some domain $U,$ then we have $\|u\|_{H^2(U)} \leq C\|f\|_{L^2(U)}$ for some constant $C.$ One way to prove this is to consider the bilinear form $\int \nabla u\cdot \nabla v$ and insert differential quotients $D_k^h u$ into the bilinear form.

The argument is briefly sketched as follows. Let's assume for simplicity that $u\in C^\infty$ and vanishes on the boundary. Then since $u$ is a weak solution,
$$
A:=-\int_U \nabla u\cdot \nabla(\partial^2_{x_jx_j}u) = \int_U f(\partial^2_{x_jx_j}u):=B .
$$
Now $A = \int |\nabla (\partial_{x_j} u)|^2,$ and $B \leq \int |f||v| dx.$ Use Cauchy-Swartz inequality to bound $B$ and make the coefficient of $\|\partial^2_{x_jx_j}u\|_{L^2}$ in the bound small, we get a good bound on $A.$ This in turn bounds the $H^2$ norm.

So far, things are easy. But I then encounter an exercise, which consider thee case of $U$ being an annulus: $U=\{x\in \mathbb R^3:r_1\leq |x|\leq r_2\}.$ The exercise ask me to prove $\|u\|_{H^2(U)} \leq C\|f\|_{L^2(U)}$ using the expression of Laplacian in **spherical polar coordinates** in $\mathbb R^3.$ I am prompted to use a similar method: multiply by a derivative (this includes $\partial_\theta (\sin \theta \partial_\theta u), \partial^2_{\phi\phi}u, \partial_{r}(r^2 \partial_r u)$) and integrate by part (just like what I have done above).

However, I struggle to make this work, because although I can still formulate a weak solution, functions such as $\frac{1}{r^2 \sin \theta}$ mix into my derivatives, which makes it extremely difficult to get a nice form $\int |\nabla (\partial_{x_j} u)|^2.$ There are simply **too many terms** to be written down on paper: the expansion of $\nabla$ in spherical coordinates includes $3$ terms, but we are to multiply by different derivatives of $u,$ so this gives $9$ terms. And coefficients doesn't appear positive or elliptic or something like that in any way (for example $\sin \theta$ is annoying). In the end I am not able to bound second-order derivatives.

**Is there a nice way to make this work?**

Comment: That's one bizarre exercise. This sounds a bit crazy, except if the person who set it forgot to mention that $f$ is radial, so that that the problem is radial, in which case it becomes a very reasonable one dimensional computation.